# How to use an enhanced for loop and an array for a dice game

Tags: java, dice

Okay so for a project I need to loop through as many dice rolls as the user wants and store them in an array to print out at the end with an advanced for loop. I have everything else done but I am stuck on how to integrate an array/advanced for loop into my existing code.

This is the class used to deal with all the dice functions:

```
package paradiseroller;

public class PairOfDice
{
    public int sides = 6;
    public int die1;   // Number showing on the first die.
    public int die2;   // Number showing on the second die.

    public PairOfDice()
    {
        // Constructor.  Rolls the dice, so that they initially
        // show some random values.
        roll();  // Call the roll() method to roll the dice.
    }

    public void roll()
    {
        // Roll the dice by setting each of the dice to be
        // a random number between 1 and 6.
        die1 = (int) (Math.random() * sides) + 1;
        die2 = (int) (Math.random() * sides) + 1;
    }

    public int getDie1()
    {
        // Return the number showing on the first die.
        return die1;
    }

    public int getDie2()
    {
        // Return the number showing on the second die.
        return die2;
    }

    public int getTotal()
    {
        // Return the total showing on the two dice.
        return die1 + die2;
    }
}
```

This is the main file in which I need to use the array and for loop:

```
package paradiseroller;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Main
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        String choice = "y";
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);

        while (choice.equalsIgnoreCase("y")) {
            PairOfDice dice;          // A variable that will refer to the dice.
            int rollCount;    // Number of times the dice have been rolled.

            dice = new PairOfDice();  // Create the PairOfDice object.
            rollCount = 0;

            System.out.println("\nIt took " + rollCount + " rolls to get a 2.");

            System.out.print("Would you like to continue? y/n");
            choice = sc.nextLine();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Just some comments on your code. 1. What's the point of `getDie1` and `getDie2` when `die1` and `die2` are public? It's common practice to make `die1` and `die2` private (that's encapsulation). 2. You can make `rollcount` a member of `PairOfDice`, and increment it in the `roll` method. Then you won't risk forgetting to update rollcount every time you call roll. 3. Instead of `Math.random` you can use [Random.nextInt](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Random.html#nextInt-int-).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For going as long as you want and storing it in a array then printing, let g be the amount the user wants

```
PairOfDice[] result = new PairOfDice[g];

// setting
for (int i = 0; i < g; i++)
{
   result[i] = new PairOfDice();
}

// printing
for (PairOfDice r : result)
{
   System.out.println(r.getDie1() + " " + r.getDie2());
}
```

Think of : as in so it's getting each int IN result and assigning it to r for each iteration.

Keep in mind this is for if you want to put it in a array (kinda bad in this case) if you just want to print immediately then you could use

```
for (int i = 0; i < g; i++)
{
   dice = new PairOfDice();
   System.out.println(dice.getDie1() + " " + dice.getDie2());
}
```

This also gives you access to the slot that it's in thanks to i.

Comment: I want to lead with I sincerely appreciate the help.

I need it to display both die separately, should I create a second for loop for this purpose or is there a way to merge the two into one?

Sorry if my question is an uninformed one, I'm still learning the basics.

Comment: You could display both die separately by instead making a array of PairOfDice, replace the for loop that fills it with the total with filling it with a new pair of dice, then in the printing array just print both on the same line.

Comment: Edited my answer so that it fits what you ask